# How to use github to update my plugin

Tags: plugin-development, github

I am trying to use github for my plugin updates, i have looked around I found this [WordPress-GitHub-Plugin-Updater](https://github.com/jkudish/WordPress-GitHub-Plugin-Updater/blob/master/plugin.php). I am now stuck and cannot get it to work.

I have created the simplest plugin to test it and to see how it works before I add it to my plugin but I cant get it to work.

The plugin I have put together to test [this is here](https://github.com/Funsella/git-update-tester)

I would really appreciate it if anyone could have a look and let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Had you tried opening issue about how it fails for you at its issue tracker? Much more likely to get attention of people familiar with it.